# How to program hardware?

Tags: embedded, hardware

I am an adept Visual Basic programmer. I wish to learn about how people program hardware. For example I have seen people create an LED watches, boxes etc. How do you achieve this? Can it be done using VB or Java? I have some experience in reading C, C++ code. I am only aware of IO in the C and C++ language.

Comment: I look at the hardware schematics and device datasheets when I program hardware.  I also find out if the device is memory mapped or I/O mapped and how the processor can communicate with the device.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably you are looking for a programmable microcontroller. If you have experience in C/C++/Java, checkout [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/). Its chip is programmed using a [C like language](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage). This "[How tos](http://sheepdogguides.com/arduino/ahttoc.htm)" page might help you get started. There are also some good books that will help you move forward:

1. [Programming Interactivity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596154143).
2. [Making Things Move DIY Mechanisms for Inventors, Hobbyists, and Artists](http://www.makingthingsmove.com/about-the-book/)

[Wiring](http://wiring.org.co/) is a platform similar to Arduino.

Also have a look at the [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) programming language. There are lot of interesting "[tiny 
computers](http://www.ultratechnology.com/)" that you can program with this rather unusual language. Here is a partial list:

1. [Forth Inc](http://www.forth.com/)
2. [Greenarrays](http://greenarraychips.com/)
3. [Zilog Z8](http://maptools.home.comcast.net/~maptools/Z8/)
4. [PIC18Fxx2](http://pic18forth.sourceforge.net/)

Two famous Forth books:

1. [Starting Forth](http://www.forth.com/starting-forth/index.html)
2. [Thinking Forth](http://thinking-forth.sourceforge.net/) (A classic in Software Engineering literature.)

Comment: Forth is great! Very different, but can be lots of fun.

Answer (score 7):

> how people program hardware

If by 'hardware' you mean a standalone device (an embedded system), then the process involves *cross-compilation*. Code for the device is written in some (high-level) language on a *host* PC, compiled, and converted to a form suitable for *downloading* onto the target device.

A cross-compiler generates executable code for a platform other than the one it is running on -- for example, an AVR cross-compiler will generate code for the AVR microcontroller, but the compiler runs on a PC. Universally, assembly and C are used, and to some extent C++, Java and Ada.

If by 'hardware' you mean some device connected to the PC via some port (serial, parallel, USB), then the programing involves interaction through that port, possibly needing a device driver as well.

> Can it be done using VB or Java?

I'm not sure about VB (perhaps there are VB compilers for WinCE and its ilk). Java is used on more complex/larger embedded systems (eg. mobile phones), mainly to develop user applications for the device.

> create an LED watches, boxes etc. How do you achieve this?

If you're interested in developing something like a LED watch, you need to learn how to program a microcontroller. At the least, you need two components: the microcontroller and some hardware which loads programs onto it (a *programer*). You may invest on a development board, or build one yourself. Naturally, you will also need the cross-compiler, and the sotware that interacts with the *programer* so that it can load code.

I'm partial to AVR, so I'd suggest that. Other options include PIC, some variant of 8051, PSoC1 and TI's MSP devices.

The AVR tool-chain is bundled in [WinAVR](http://winavr.sourceforge.net/), and it includes avr-gcc (cross-compiler frontend), avrdude (software that interacts with the programer hardware) and a C library (avr-libc) + a bunch of useful tools. Programing hardware can be as simple as [DAPA/bsd](http://www.bsdhome.com/avrdude/) to USB based ones (AVRISP, USBasp, Usbprog) etc.

Or, if your PC still has a parallel port, you can try to control say a set of LEDs using an application written in VB. Check http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm for details.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend starting out with something like an arduino, which is a good place to get started with programming close to the hardware. It's a prototyping board with some built-in leds and other things, depending on which model you get. You can use C/C++, or any other language which can be cross-compiled to a format which is compatible with the target hardware (ATMega microcontroller I believe on the arduino).

Check out: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=arduino&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to connect something to the computer serial/parallel port and 'talk' to it, you can use most languages. In Visual Basic you'll need a dll to achieve this. Java may be able to do it too.
If you want to program a microcontroler chip, you'd best learn C, because this is the language used to program most of them, although some of them accept basic, java, processing and C++.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of basic stamps you can use to get your feet wet.  parallax for example made their business on basic based embedded systems.  If you want to move forward at that programming level you really need to learn C for the most coverage, and I highly recommend assembler as well, at least a few different instruction sets.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Gadgeteer](http://www.netmf.com/gadgeteer/). I got to play with a kit a few weeks ago, and it's amazing fun. You can't currently do VB, but you can do C# and [VB is coming very soon](http://blog.vbmagic.net/2012/01/25/gadgeteer/).